# What's the best way to embed video in a Windows Mobile 6 application?

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, video, compact-framework

App needs to run on the .Net Compact Framework v.3.5. Video can be any format, but I do need to be able to know when it's finished playing, so I can start another one.

I'm hoping for a method that doesn't involve unmanaged code, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to embed it using ActiveX Hosting.  There is an [MSDN tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446515.aspx) on it (note there is a [bug in the MS-published code](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2008/08/14/BugInMSDNActiveXHostingCode.aspx)).  If you want a more friendly way, then OpenNETCF has a [commercial control](http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/Controls/MediaPlayerControls/tabid/264/Default.aspx) for it as well.

Answer (score 0):

The version of Flash Lite that can be downloaded from Adobe 2.1 won't support video so you can't embed that as an ActiveX control. Your only real option is to follow @ctacke's advice and embed Windows Media Player, or other media player that offers a ActiveX control you can use (I'm not aware of any - sorry!).

Answer (score -1):

Silverlight is coming to windows mobile 6, its in super elite beta right now, maybe get in on that action.

Comment: Silverlight is a useless suggestion. I think you need to assume he needs something today or in the not too distant future. Microsoft have promised and not delivered on Silverlight for mobile devices. Let's hope it's ready for PDC 2008!